# will property be overwritten by later property file?

Tags: ant

if i have 2 properties file to be loaded and both contains the same property ${Product.Version}, which will be taken into account in my build.xml script and why?

**build.xml**

```
...
<property file="sort.properties" />
<property file="master.properties" />
...
<echo message="${Product.Version} />
```

**sort.properties**

```
Product.Version = 7.00
```

**master.properties**

```
Product.Version = 6.00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Product.Version will be equal to 7.0, once a property is set within ant it will not be overwritten by another attempt to set the property later in the script.

Comment: and if you need to change the value of a property after it has been set, you can use the `var` task from [antcontrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)